# Error while printing the subimages while subtracting 1 from the counter

Tags: python

does anyone why I get the error on the 'subimages' ?. I really don't understand what is wrong and I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

The subimage_stats_fid is:

```
subimage_stats_fid = open(path_upwards + config.data_path + rgb_output_data_path + file_name_for_subimage_stats, 'w')
```

full_image_path_list = glob.glob(path_upwards + config.data_path + input_data_path + '*/*' + input_image_extension)

> ```
> print(f'{image_name}: {counter-1} subimages')
> subimage_stats_fid.write(f'{image_name}: {counter-1} subimages\n')
> ```

I get the following error message:

> ```
> print(f'{image_name}: {counter-1} subimages')
>                                            ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Comment: What is `subimage_stats_fid`?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on how to better frame your question.

Comment: @ywbaek I have shared the changes

Comment: @Charalambos what is the python version are you using? If it is <3.6, then f string syntax won't work.

Comment: @ywbaek I am using 3.6 . Any recommendation of how to change it?

Comment: @Charalambos It's possible that you have multiple versions of Python. What is the output of `import sys; print(sys.version)`?

Comment: @ywbaek I have recently upgraded sys, so its the newest version